# Where can I find a replacement part for a seatpost collar?

Tags: parts, seatpost

I have a foldable bike and I need to constantly adjust the height of my bike seat, the problem is that one of the pieces of the seatpost collar is totally worn out and needs replacement.

The part that I need is depicted in this image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rs6Wk.jpg

Ideally I wouldn't want to spend too much money on this. Does anyone have a creative solution to this?

Comment: I don't know if you can buy individual rubber pieces, but you could probably replace the entire seat post clamp for under $10.  Possibly under $5 if you have a popular size. Check your local bike store, they should be able to help you find one that fits your bike, as there are many different sizes.

Comment: In addition to what @Kibbee has suggested, if you have a bike shop near you that deals in **used** bikes, you can almost certainly get one for under $5.

Comment: Take the clamp to a good hardware store.  They will have a drawer full of assorted washers and bushings.  Likely a brass or nylon washer can be found that will do the job nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Through a lot of searching, I can't say there's anywhere that sells that specific part; however, you may have some luck contacting the manufacturer or distributor directly.

But, a much easier and simpler solution would be to replace the clamp/collar entirely. It's probably pretty worn out if you're missing that piece anyway!

Check out the great selection over at [Jenson USA](http://www.jensonusa.com/Seatpost-Collars), or your favorite LBS.